# IOS9 Push notifications dialog appears after delete and launch app with xCode7

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I have an application, it uses APNS, so I have code that subscribes to notifications, and everything works fine. But every time I reinstall app, and run it with xcode, I get allow push notification dialog. Every time. 
I found hundreds questions about how to achieve this dialog again, but none - how to stop achieving them. I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems known IOS9 bug, here is a [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/50273#50273) for developer forum and still no response from apple and no solution: